# Creating Smart Categories With the Visual Merchandiser

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise

I am currently trying to add a custom attribute to the visual merchandiser so that I can create a smart category from it.

However the attribute doesn't appear in the list on the merchandiser (Stores > Configuration > Catalogue > Visual Merchandiser). I have been informed that this may be due to the fact that the attribute in question can have multiple values selected for each product e.g the attribute recipient could have the values For Him, For Fathers and For Students for product X.

Could you please let me know how to get this attribute to appear in the visual merchandiser so that I can use it to make a smart category?

Answer (score 1):

The visual merchandiser does not support multi select attributes as far as I know.

If you need more complex rules you should give a try at elasticsuite, which provide an comparable feature which is more usable as a matter of UX.

You can find it here for free : https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite

Disclosure : I am elasticsuite lead developer